# Search different pattern in every line (grep/awk/sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

lets say that I have text file:

```
2016-02-10  [id-2555] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001067,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10  [id-2555] hello > bye (1120 > 1067.444)
2016-02-10  [id-2556] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001267,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10  [id-2556] hello > bye (1520 > 1267.555)
2016-02-10  [id-2556] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001367,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10  [id-2556] hello > bye (1820 > 1367.666)
```

Is it possible to check if in every line Floatnumber is equal to second number in bracket? 
Let's say:

```
 "Floatnumber":0.001067 == int(1067.444)/100000?
```

for know I round the 2nd number:

```
awk '{ int($11)/1000000 }'
```

but I don't have idea how to change pattern in every line and match it.

edit1.
Is it possible if pattern match print datajson or eq flower?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It isn't particularly easy, but it is possible.  You might set the field separator pattern to cover colon, comma, space and right parenthesis.  Then you can get the float number field (do you need to check the tag before, or can you assume fixed positiions?) and the last field and do the checking.

Comment: we can compare it and then if the pattern match I can print json data, or single field eg. flower

Answer (score 1):

It's easier using `perl`:

```
$ cat data
2016-02-10 [id-2555] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001067,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10 [id-2555] hello > bye (1120 > 1067)
2016-02-10 [id-2556] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001267,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10 [id-2556] hello > bye (1520 > 1267)
2016-02-10 [id-2556] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001367,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10 [id-2556] hello > bye (1820 > 1367)
2016-02-10 [id-2556] data:{"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.000367,"animal":"cat"} 2016-02-10 [id-2556] hello > bye (1820 > 1368)
# I have added a 4th line, where the condition does not match.

$ perl -nE 'm/"Floatnumber":([0-9.]*)/; my $a=$1; m/> ([0-9]*)\)$/; my $b=$1; say ((($a *1000000) == $b)?"true":"false");' <data
true
true
true
false
```

Explanation:
Match the float number after `"Floatnumber":` & save it in `$a`. Match the integer in the end & store in `$b`.
If `$a * 1000000 == $b`, print true. Else print false.

**EDIT1**:
Print the data if match found:

```
perl -nE 'm/"Floatnumber":([0-9.]*)/; my $a=$1; m/> ([0-9]*)\)$/; my $b=$1; m/data:{([^ ]*)}/; say ((($a *1000000) == $b)?$1:"NULL");' <data
"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001067,"animal":"cat"
"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001267,"animal":"cat"
"flower":"hmm","Floatnumber":0.001367,"animal":"cat"
NULL
```

Print the flower value if match found:

```
perl -nE 'm/"Floatnumber":([0-9.]*)/; my $a=$1; m/> ([0-9]*)\)$/; my $b=$1; m/"flower":"([^"]*)"/; say ((($a *1000000) == $b)?$1:"NULL");' <data
hmm
hmm
hmm
NULL
```

Comment: Nice solution, but is it possible if true: print datajson or single field inside eg flower?

Comment: Yes, but your question did not ask for that... :) Also, if it does not match, what should be printed? something like `flower == null`? or just empty line? or just skip that line?

Comment: I edited main post and add edit. if not match, false is ok :)

Comment: You need only `flower`, or entire `data`?

Comment: Is it possible to choose, entire data, flower, animal?

Comment: nice !! But i have one more question. I edited log, and the number in braces is float. Is it possible to convert it to int and then compare?

Comment: I tried write is as perl -nE 'm/"Floatnumber":([0-9.]*)/; my $a=$1; m/> ([0-9]*)\)$/; my $b=$1; m/data:{([^ ]*)}/; say ((($a *1000000) == int($b))?$1:"NULL");' but its not working :(

Comment: "the number in braces is float"? Your regex needs to be changed to include decimal point. `m/> ([0-9.]*))$/`

Comment: If you keep editing your requirements, it will be impossible to keep providing you updated answers. So, either provide the exact data & exact expected output or you (yourself) will need to modify the provided answer(s) to suit your updated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
awk -F'[:,()]|[[:blank:]]+' '{print $7*1000000==int($18)?"same":"different", $0}'

# or print only lines where the values are the same:
awk -F'[:,()]|[[:blank:]]+' '$7*1000000==int($18){print}'

# values are the same and contain "2555" in the string
awk -F'[:,()]|[[:blank:]]+' '$7*1000000==int($18) && /2555/{print}'
```

The `-F` is a regular expression for the Fied Separator.

Comment: I checked and it's not working. First awk print everything. 2nd nothing and 3rd also nothing :(

Comment: Edited, I forgot your last field was a float, well, adapt the type casting to your needs to get a match ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk` and `jq`

```
awk -F"[:, )]" '$8==int($(NF-1))/1000000{
    f=gensub(/[^:]+:([^}]+}) .+/, "\\1", "g",$0);
    print f
}'
```

Pipe the awk output to `jq -r '.flower'`